# Could not start QuickBooks (from Service)

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have created a DLL that calls into `QBFC13`. It works just fine in the development environments I'm working with. (VS10 and a lite version embedded in an application.) However, when my DLL is called from a Service running on that machine, I'm getting a `(0x80040408): Could not start QuickBooks` when my DLL then attempts to open QB via the API.

I using an application name that has full access in QB in the OpenConnection line, and the path to the file is correct. `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files`

Looking in the forums, I don't see anything that corresponds to this scenario, so I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight.

Comment: Are you running the service as a user that has access to the quickbooks application? That would be the first thing I would check.

Answer (score 1):

QuickBooks integrations *do not work* when running as a Windows service.

This is a well known, long standing, and unlikely to be fixed by Intuit issue.

Read more:

- https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/805619-getting-error-2147220472-could-not-start-quickbooks
- [Getting error -2147220472 (Could not start Quickbooks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905010/getting-error-2147220472-could-not-start-quickbooks)